# Where will Python search for .NET assemblies?

Tags: c#, python, .net, c++-cli

We have a C# application and we need to provide Python scripting interface. Now it's implemented in a way that:

- A managed scripting library (compiled as a DLL) does all the core work
- A C++/CLI wrapper (wraps around the managed library and is compiled as a static library) does all the native-managed data translation
- A boost extension project (BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE) (compiled as a dynamic library with the extension manually changed to pyd) talks to the C++/CLI wrapper layer.

The problem I have is that every time any python app tries to use the interface, it will complain the core managed assembly cannot be found. I have to place it either in the Python installation directory, or deploy it into the GAC.

I enabled the Windows Fusion logging and saw that it will only probe the assembly in the Python directory, I wonder if there is a way to direct Python to search for the .NET assembly in our application installation directory, or rather, any custom directory?

I tried all approaches in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144089/expand-python-search-path-to-other-source) but that does not work for me. Any help will be highly appreciated!

PS:

- We know that there are other python options like IronPython or Python .NET but we need to be backward compatible so a C++ interface is also required.
- In case you are curious what error I get, here it is:

  Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ScriptingInterface, Version=1.3.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=160df4f7a3973cc2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  at NativeCommunicator.{ctor}(NativeCommunicator* )

Comment: Kindly add these comments to the question itself

Comment: did you append your paths to sys.path in python?

Comment: @denfromufa  Yes, I added my path into sys.path and I can tell that from the console display. But still it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Esentially to fix the problem you have to:

1. In your python script as a very first line you have to call "init".
2. "Init" is a function which you add in your .pyd module
3. In Init method you simply register a hook for resolving assemblies.
4. In the hook you have a chance to load your assemblies from whatever directory you want.

Link below might have be helpful for you:
[Loading Mixed-Mode C++/CLI .dll (and dependencies) dynamically from unmanaged c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016663/loading-mixed-mode-c-cli-dll-and-dependencies-dynamically-from-unmanaged-c)